# Restrict Access to the Microsoft Store

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy

I am trying to disable the windows store locally our Windows 10 machines. In group policy I set **Turn off the Store application** to **Enabled**:

[image]

I then rebooted the machine. When I tried to access the Microsoft Store, I was still able to.

Looking at the registry, I can see that the policy did change the **RemoveWindowsStore** value:

[image]

**Why is it not restricting access to the Microsoft Store? Am I missing something?**

Comment: That's a machine-level registry entry, so have you rebooted yet?

Comment: Yes, of course I have, several times. I guess I should have stated that instead.  I fixed my question. After a reboot the computer still has access to the Windows Store.

Comment: @Ramhound From the policy: "If you enable this setting, access to the Store application is denied".

Comment: Enabling it sets the RemoveWindowsStore to 1 and Disabling it sets it to 0. So, Enabling it should restrict access to the Microsoft Store.  However, it is not doing anything.

Comment: I removed my comment.  I was reading the description, hoping that it was like another similar setting, that expected to be disabled in order for it to be allowed.  Don't ask me what that policy was I don't have it handy and besides if I knew what it was offhand, I wouldn't have thought, it was this policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Windows 10 version 1511, the Windows Store no longer respects this setting unless you have Windows 10 **Enterprise**. From Darrell Gorter, a Microsoft employee, in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9514c7a6-991b-48b0-95ab-33edfc029c52/windows-10-enterprise-disable-store-feature?forum=win10itprogeneral):

> Hello,
>
> The group policy for disabling the Windows Store was changed to only work with the Windows 10 Enterprise edition

If you only have Windows 10 Pro, you'll need to remove the Windows Store app. Note that using `Remove-AppxPackage` only applies to the current user. You could create a logon script that runs that when anybody logs on, or you could use this command (requires admin) to remove the Store from the list of apps that are installed when a new user logs on ([source](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-remove-the-store-app-in-windows-10/)):

```
Remove-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.701.14.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

Note that this will not remove the Store for users that have already logged in; they'll need to have the `Remove-AppxPackage` command run. Therefore, the best time to do `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage` is before any end user gets the machine (i.e. at deployment time). But once the Store is gone, it can't be easily reinstalled since there's no store from which to install "modern" apps.

Answer (score 3):

This should uninstall the Store, rather than disable it (it will be gone and you'll need to type another command to restore it).

1. Start -> type `windows powershell`
2. Right click the app shown and take **run as administrator* *
3. Wait until the cursor is ready and then paste:

   `Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage`
4. Key in <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait. It should remove the icon from Start at least.

Just tested on my Windows 10 x64.

[Here is some info on Get-AppxPackage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856044.aspx)

Comment: So they would need to deploy a script that ran this on every machine?

Comment: @Raystafarian better ask someone more expert in powershell to find a suitable network command. I'm just a beginner :)

Answer (score 0):

Locate the "Disable all apps from the Windows Store" setting.
Set it to Disabled.
This will prevent running the Store app as well as any store apps.